# why do i run into a runtime error (range) when im trying to execute a timestamp user defined function

Tags: excel, vba, range, user-defined-functions, password-protection

I have a sheet which i want people to populate manually

One of these columns is for a date and a timestamp, rather then manual entry for this as its pretty awkward for noobs on excel i have made a user defined function and assigned to a button... select cell you want timestamp in ...click button i have made..timestamp appears in cell...all works perfectly

HOWEVER

I need to lock and protect some columns on a sheet and leave just a table for people to populate
When i do this it runs into a runtime error about range?! i dont understand why as it is only one cell within the unprotected table that needs updating?

Code to user defined function below

```
Sub Timestamp()

Dim ts As Date

With Selection
.Value = Now
.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy h:mm:ss AM/PM"

End With

End Sub
```

any help appreciated

Thanks a million

Comment: Did you set the `cells` for allow for edit before `protect sheet`?

Comment: all i did different was protect the tab sheet (i unlocked all the cells in the table beforhand so users can manipulate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will always recommend to `protect` your worksheet using VBA if you need execute VBA code on the protected sheet, so that it can bypassed the protected range and update your timestamp successfully:

Copy this code to `ThisWorkBook` will protected specific WS but allow VBA to write value on locked cell

```
Sub Workbook_Open()
Sheet1.Protect Password:="xxx", UserInterfaceOnly:=True, 
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you sir I will try and report back toyou

Comment: Sure, accept the answer if solve your problem :)

Comment: Hi what if there are multiple sheets i need to protect ...basically i have 5 input sheets which need populating. i need to protect all 5, i then have one sheet which consolidates them all using VBA

Comment: You can use the code to protect more that a sheet, when you consolidate them all using VBA will still work, please try and see first.

Comment: Awesome!! it did indeed work!! you are a legend sir :D

Comment: Welcome, glad it help you :)